# Filter Calendar view by Title in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

i want to filter calendar view using title field. Is it possible to filter calendar view without make changes in modify view ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean under "without make changes in modify view"

Answer (score 0):

You could form a query string involving FilterField and FilterValue. Append these values to the CalendarView.aspx page. Let me know if this works.